# How can I make the TextField open as long as the button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having a trouble here, I created a choices wherein if the user clicked the `Other's` button, the TextField will be open, but the problem is, when I click the `Others` button again, it will not closed.

What I want here is keep the TextField Open, as long as the button is `highlighted and close it when the user` unclicked` it

In this image, I clicked it, so It will `open`

[image: First Image]

But when I clicked it again.

[image: Second Image]

It is still open.

So what I did here is I rendered the `Question` as well as the `Choices`, and check if the `choices's essay === true`, then show the TextField

```
{
    "_id": "642d892955e310c62e46b9d3",
    "title": "Question Sample",
    "choices": [
        {
            "choices": "GAD Orientation",
            "essay": false,
        },
        {
            "choices": "Gender Sensitivity Training",
            "essay": false,
        },
        {
            "choices": "Gender Mainstreaming",
            "essay": false,
        },
        {
            "choices": "GAD Planning and Budgeting",
            "essay": false,
        },
        {
            "choices": "GAD Analysis Tools",
            "essay": false,
        },
        {
            "choices": "Harmonized Gender and Development Guidelines",
            "essay": false,
        },
        {
            "choices": "Gender Mainstreaming Evaluation Framework",
            "essay": false,
        },
        {
            "choices": "Others, enumerate",
            "essay": true,
        },
        {
            "choices": "None",
            "essay": false,
        }
    ],
    "type_of_question": true,
}
```

So what I did here is, I checked the `choice.essay === true` then Open it.
Part4.js

```
  const [openChoiceId, setOpenChoiceId] = useState(null);
  const handleClick = (choice) => {
    if (choice.essay === true) {
      setOpenChoiceId(choice.choices);
    } else {
    }
  };


{currentChoices.map((choice, index) =>(
                  <Grid item xs={6} key={index}>
                   <label className="toggle-button" key={choice.id} onClick={() => handleClick(choice)}>
                   <input className="toggle-button__state" type="checkbox" name="choice" value={choice.choices} onChange={handleChange}/>
                   <span className="toggle-button__text">{choice.choices}</span>
                   
                   <Box sx={{position:'absolute', bottom: 50, left: 0, width: '100%', px: 2}}>
                   {openChoiceId === choice.choices && choice.essay === true && 
                   <TextField
                    id="filled-multiline-static"
                    label="Others"
                    fullWidth
                    multiline
                    rows={3}
                    name="essay" onChange={handleTextFieldChange} 
                    variant="outlined"
                  />}

                   </Box>

                 </label>
                  </Grid>
                  
              ))}
```

EDIT:

When I tried this.

```
const handleClick = (choice) => {
      setOpenChoiceId(choice.choices);
  };
```

[image: Third image]

**Additional Info**

I created a codesandbox here, I hope this one helps

https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-star-wj57um?file=/src/sampleData.js

HandleChange comes from my parent component, so this is how it looks like

```
const [answer,setAnswer] = useState({
      email: email,
      category: type,
      affiliation: affiliation,
      part: `part${getSurveyPart}`,
      choice: "",
      essay: "",
     })
```

HandleChange.js

```
   const handleChange = (e) => {
            const value = e.target.value;
            const inputType = e.target.type;
        
            let newChoice = answer.choice; // initialize newChoice with the current choice array
        
            if (inputType === 'radio') {
            newChoice = [value];
            } else if (inputType === 'checkbox') {
            const isChecked = e.target.checked;
            const choiceIndex = answer.choice.indexOf(value);
            if (isChecked) {
                newChoice = [...answer.choice, value];
            } else {
                newChoice = [
                ...answer.choice.slice(0, choiceIndex),
                ...answer.choice.slice(choiceIndex + 1),
                ];
            }
            }
        
            const newAnswer = { ...answer, choice: newChoice };

            setAnswer(newAnswer);
        };
```

Comment: can you add what handleChange looks like? also if i am not wrong there is only one text field. Right? You should not have that in the map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need a simple boolean state and based on the selected choice you can toggle its value.

Replace

```
const [openChoiceId, setOpenChoiceId] = useState(null);

const handleClick = (choice) => {
    if (choice.essay === true) {
      setOpenChoiceId(choice.choices);
    } else {
    }
  };
```

With

```
const [visibleTextField, setVisibleTextField] = useState(false);

const handleChange = (e, choice) => {
  if (choice.essay) {
    setVisibleTextField(e.target.checked);
  }
};
```

and condition to show text field should be replaced with

```
{
  visibleTextField && (
    <TextField
      id="filled-multiline-static"
      label="Others"
      fullWidth
      multiline
      rows={3}
      name="essay"
      onChange={handleTextFieldChange}
      variant="outlined"
    />
  );
}
```

Listen to change event instead of click like below

```
<input
    className="toggle-button__state"
    type="checkbox"
    name="choice"
    value={choice.choices}
    onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, choice)}
  />
```

Final code

```
const [visibleTextField, setVisibleTextField] = useState(false);

const handleChange = (e, choice) => {
  if (choice.essay) {
    setVisibleTextField(e.target.checked);
  }
};
{
  currentChoices.map((choice, index) => (
    <Grid item xs={6} key={index}>
      <label className="toggle-button" key={choice.id}>
        <input
          className="toggle-button__state"
          type="checkbox"
          name="choice"
          value={choice.choices}
          onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, choice)}
        />
        <span className="toggle-button__text">{choice.choices}</span>
      </label>

      <Box
        sx={{
          position: 'absolute',
          bottom: 50,
          left: 0,
          width: '100%',
          px: 2,
        }}
      >
        {visibleTextField && (
          <TextField
            id="filled-multiline-static"
            label="Others"
            fullWidth
            multiline
            rows={3}
            name="essay"
            variant="outlined"
          />
        )}
      </Box>
    </Grid>
  ));
}
```

Comment: It did the same thing.

Comment: No, in your code you are not hiding it back, I have revamped it in a simpler code.

Comment: I tried this, but when I click the `textfield` it automatically close.

Comment: Updated code after verifying it on code sandbox demo link that you have provided. see working example here https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-knuth-tvf1vv?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

When you click any of the buttons, make sure initially to set all "choices.essay" value to false. You can do it by:

```
choices.forEach(item => item.essay = false);
```

Then, you either open or close the essay textarea on button click. If the essay is true, you set to false. If essay value is false, you set to true.

```
const handleClick = (choice) => {
    if(choice.essay === true) {
        choice.essay = false
    } else {
        choice.essay = true
    }
}
```

And, when you render  component, make sure to render it by only when "choice.essay === true". You can remove "openChoiceId === choice.choice" statement. It goes like this

```
{choice.essay === true && 
    <TextField 
        id="filled-multiline-static"
        label="Others"
        fullWidth
        multiline
        rows={3}
        name="essay" onChange={handleTextFieldChange} 
        variant="outlined"
    />}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the edited code it looks like you are selecting multiple choices and when you select other you need to have the input shown up. You can do something like below to achieve this.

```
const [openChoices, setOpenChoices] = useState([]);
  const handleChange = (e, choice) => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      setOpenChoices(prev => [...prev, choice.choices]);
    } else {
      setOpenChoices(prev => prev.filter(p => p !== choice.choices));
    }
  };
```

And in the JSX

```
{currentChoices.map((choice, index) =>(
                  <Grid item xs={6} key={index}>
                   <label className="toggle-button" key={choice.id}>
                   <input className="toggle-button__state" type="checkbox" name="choice" value={choice.choices} onChange={e => handleChange(e, choice)}/>
                   <span className="toggle-button__text">{choice.choices}</span>
                   
                   <Box sx={{position:'absolute', bottom: 50, left: 0, width: '100%', px: 2}}>
                   {openChoices.includes(choice.choices) && choice.essay === true && 
                   <TextField
                    id="filled-multiline-static"
                    label="Others"
                    fullWidth
                    multiline
                    rows={3}
                    name="essay" onChange={handleTextFieldChange} 
                    variant="outlined"
                  />}

                   </Box>

                 </label>
                  </Grid>
                  
              ))}
```

Comment: I tried this, but when I click other choice, it closes the textfield

Comment: Have you tried edited answer. I guess that is expected as another choice doesn't have essay true

Comment: I tried the edited, the `TextField` didn't open

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple thing you that needs to be fixed

first you are not checking wether the checkbox is actually checked or not so you can either remove it or add it to the state

```
  onClick={(e) => handleClick(choice,e)}

  const handleClick = (choice,e) => {
    setOpenChoiceId(e.currentTarget.checked ? choice : {});
  };
```

i removed the span with the text and instead added a label with an htmlFor
so whenever you click on the text it clicks on the actual checkbox
and right now the onClick event handler need to be on the checkbox not the label

```
    <label
      className="toggle-button"
      htmlFor={choice._id}
    >
      {choice.choices}
      </label>

      <input
        className="toggle-button__state"
        id={choice._id}
        type="checkbox"
        name="choice"
      onClick={(e) => handleClick(choice,e)}
        value={choice.choices}
      />
```

last thing is that you are doing a wrong conditional statement

to display the textField you need to be checking against the state and not what you were doing previously
also the conditional chaining `.?` is because the openChoiceId will be set to an empty when the none of checkboxes are checked and will be an object and won't have essay as a property

```
{openChoiceId?.essay === true && (jsx goes here) }
```